# VHDL using a FIFO with multidimensional data array

Tags: vhdl, instantiation, ram, primitive, fifo

Good evening,

I have a design where I am receiving 7 16-bit streams of data at 400Mhz.

I need this data to be presented as 26 16-bit streams of data at 100Mhz.

As it can be seen, I am receiving 28 16-bit streams of data at 100Mhz, which would result in more data constantly coming in then going out. To solve this, I drop 1/14 sets (2/28 sets) of 26 16-bit streams.

I currently have an elaborate state machine that stores the data into a LUT by counting by 7, moving to the next state when 26 is reached, and carrying over the remainder to the next row in the table, and then I read back the LUT at the 100Mhz rate with a counter up to 14 for the 14 sets of 26 16-bit streams stored. On the 14th read, the last row is not read and the data from the 13th read is repeated now for 2 100Mhz clocks.

I want to move this from a giant LUT to a BRAM/FIFO. Because of the nature of the design, a FIFO obviously stands out more to me, except I've never really implemented one so I have a few questions:

I plan on using a FIFO18E1/36E1 primitive instantiation. From what I can tell, this primitive expects a std_logic_vector as its input. I obviously cannot just do a for loop generate statement for each data bus, as this would create 7 FIFOs and now my data isn't necessarily in order when I go to recall it unless I'm keeping track of the order, which removes the benefit of switching from my state machine to the FIFO. So, is there any effective way to instantiate a FIFO primitive where I would not have to lie my data flat to get this to work? Or would this force me to either lie my data flat or design my own FIFO instance?

If not and I still wanted to use this, I would have to lie my data streams flat as they go in and then convert them back to an array when reading. So my data_width generic would be set to 7*16 bits = 112 bits wide. In the Xilinx documentation though, it states:

This component can be configured and used as a 4-bit wide by 8K deep, 9-bit by 4K deep, 18-bit by 2K deep, 36-bit wide by 1K deep, or 72-bit wide by 512 deep synchronous or dual-clock (asynchronous) FIFO RAM with all associated FIFO flags.

Does this mean that a single instance of this primitive would already not support this because my bit width is too large? Would having this as an issue force me to instantiate a second FIFO to keep track of the "overflow", and then I would have to recall partial data from each FIFO on the read cycle?

Also, my next issue then is that there is only one data_width generic, so it seems to me that these are identical on the read and write side. On my read side though, I want my data width to be 26*16 bits out. Does this mean that my data_width generic has to be set to the worst case size of the input/output? This would then force me to pad the 26*16 - 7*16 = 304 bits as 0s to get the data to line up. Also, if I am correct in my multiple instantiations of this primitive to match the data_width generic, I would be forced to create ceil(26*16 / 72) = 6 instances of this primitive in order for it to work.

If all of this is true, then it seems that using this primitive is not as efficient as I expected and in order to increase the efficiency I would be forced to design my own FIFO, correct? Although my other question then is that on the Xilinx primitive the FIFO is listed as non-inferred. So, if I were to design my own FIFO, what resources would it end up consuming? Would it be some elaborate dual aspect block ram with read and write pointers?

Any recommendations for this would be greatly appreciated. Sorry there is not any code by the way, but most of this is just understanding the FIFO primitive conceptually anyway to know whether my design could support use of it.

Comment: TL;DR please use some diagrams to explain your story. State transitions, block diagram, etc. Also show what you tried to code already, even of it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you allowed to loose data? What do you mean with `lie my data flat`? The [FIFO implementations](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/tree/master/src/fifo) of the [PoC-Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) support any FIFO sizes (depth and width) as well as LUTRAM or BlockRAM based data backends.